# Manipulação de parents e siblings JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com uma dúvida em JQuery.
Eu tenho o seguinte código, exemplo:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="md-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="md-check">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" hidden="hidden">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_1">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" hidden="hidden">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_2">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" hidden="hidden">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_3">
</div>
```

O que eu preciso fazer é que quando alguém marcar o **checkbox1**, ele deve mostrar os inputs das `divs` que estão com o atributo **hidden**.

No caso seria algo como subir até o *pai* do **checkbox**, depois subir até o *pai* dessa **div**, depois setar como *visivel* as **divs** *vizinhas*.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Quando desmarcar o checkbox, deve ocultar as div's também?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo como isso?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkbox1").click(function(){
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if(checked)
            $(this).parent().parent().siblings("div[hidden=hidden]").each(function(i, div) {
                $(div).removeAttr("hidden").show();
            });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="md-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="md-check">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" hidden="hidden">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_1">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" hidden="hidden">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_2">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" hidden="hidden">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_3">
</div>
```

Esse é um jeito de fazer, exatamente como você descreveu: a partir do checkbox, obtem-se o pai do pai e então os nós do mesmo nível que tenham o atributo `hidden`. Para cada um, remove-se o atributo e torna-o visível.

Comment: isso mesmo, muito obrigado cara